# Java mouse picking on diamond tiled map

Tags: java, swing, isometric, mouselistener, mouse-picking

Ok, im at my wits end. I am trying to create a small isometric tile map thats bigger then the screen witha viewpoint i can modify with mouse dragging.
I got the drawing right (i think), i got the dragging working, just do't seem to be able to get the mouse picking right.
I have made it so far that i get the tile nearly right, but its off by about half a tiles size and i can't find a way to make up that offset.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MapView {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame test = new JFrame("IsoView");
        test.setSize(800, 600);
        MapViewPane pane = new MapViewPane();
        test.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        test.getContentPane().add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MapViewPane extends JPanel
            implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

        private BufferedImage BackImage;
        BufferedImage GrassTile, SelectedBorder;
        private Point MousePoint, PrevView, ViewLocation, Selected;
        private boolean Dragging;
        private int mapwidth, mapheight, tilecount;

        public MapViewPane() {
            super();
            this.setOpaque(true);
            createAssets();
            tilecount = 30;
            mapwidth = GrassTile.getWidth() * tilecount;
            mapheight = GrassTile.getHeight() * tilecount;
            ViewLocation = new Point(0, mapheight / 2);
            Selected = new Point(-1, -1);
            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

        private void createAssets() {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc =
                    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
            GrassTile = gc.createCompatibleImage(128,
                    64, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
            Graphics g = GrassTile.getGraphics();
            Polygon poly = new Polygon();
            poly.addPoint(0, 32);
            poly.addPoint(64, 0);
            poly.addPoint(128, 32);
            poly.addPoint(64, 64);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillPolygon(poly);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawPolygon(poly);
            g.dispose();
            SelectedBorder = gc.createCompatibleImage(128,
                    64, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
            g = SelectedBorder.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawPolygon(poly);
            g.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            //super.paint(g);
            Rectangle visiblerec = this.getVisibleRect();
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(visiblerec.x, visiblerec.y,
                    visiblerec.width, visiblerec.height);
            checkBackImage();
            Graphics bg = BackImage.getGraphics();
            drawGrassGrid(bg);
            bg.dispose();
            g.drawImage(BackImage, 0, 0, this);
        }

        private void drawGrassGrid(Graphics g) {
            int dx = 0;
            int dy = 0;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, BackImage.getWidth(), BackImage.getHeight());
            for (int x = 0; x < tilecount; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < tilecount; y++) {
                    dx = x * GrassTile.getWidth() / 2
                            - y * GrassTile.getWidth() / 2;
                    dy = x * GrassTile.getHeight() / 2
                            + y * GrassTile.getHeight() / 2;
                    dx -= ViewLocation.x;
                    dy -= ViewLocation.y;
                    g.drawImage(GrassTile, dx, dy, this);
                    if ((x == Selected.x) && (y == Selected.y)) {
                        g.drawImage(SelectedBorder, dx, dy, this);
                    }
                    g.drawString("(" + x + "," + y + ")", dx, dy
                            + GrassTile.getHeight() / 2);
                }
            }
        }

        private void checkBackImage() {
            if ((BackImage == null) || (BackImage.getWidth() != this.getWidth())
                    || (BackImage.getHeight() != this.getHeight())) {
                GraphicsConfiguration gc =
                        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
                BackImage = gc.createCompatibleImage(this.getWidth(),
                        this.getHeight(), Transparency.BITMASK);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (Dragging) {
                ViewLocation.x = PrevView.x + MousePoint.x - e.getX();
                ViewLocation.y = PrevView.y + MousePoint.y - e.getY();
                if (ViewLocation.x < -mapwidth / 2) {
                    ViewLocation.x = -mapwidth / 2;
                }
                if (ViewLocation.y < -mapheight / 2 + this.getHeight()) {
                    ViewLocation.y = -mapheight / 2 + this.getHeight();
                }
                if (ViewLocation.x > mapwidth / 2 - this.getWidth()
                        + GrassTile.getWidth()) {
                    ViewLocation.x = mapwidth / 2 - this.getWidth()
                            + GrassTile.getWidth();
                }
                if (ViewLocation.y > mapheight / 2 + this.getHeight()) {
                    ViewLocation.y = mapheight / 2 + this.getHeight();
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!Dragging) {
                int x = (GrassTile.getWidth() * (e.getY() + ViewLocation.y)
                        + GrassTile.getHeight() * (e.getX() + ViewLocation.x))
                        / (GrassTile.getWidth() * GrassTile.getHeight());
                int y = (GrassTile.getWidth() * (e.getY() + ViewLocation.y)
                        - GrassTile.getHeight() * (e.getX() + ViewLocation.x))
                        / (GrassTile.getWidth() * GrassTile.getHeight());

//      int x = (int) Math.floor((e.getY() + ViewLocation.y)
//              / (double) GrassTile.getHeight() - (e.getX() + ViewLocation.x)
//              / (double) GrassTile.getWidth());
//      int y = (int) Math.floor((e.getY() + ViewLocation.y)
//              / (double) GrassTile.getHeight() + (e.getX() + ViewLocation.x)
//              / (double) GrassTile.getWidth());

                Selected.setLocation(x, y);
                repaint();
                System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if ((e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) && !Dragging) {
                MousePoint = e.getPoint();
                PrevView = new Point(ViewLocation);
                Dragging = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            Dragging = false;
            MousePoint = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I have some formulas in the click method commented out wich i tried, but they dont work (x and y axis are inverted that way, havent tried to figure out why yet).
Would realy appreciate if someone can point me to the mistake i'm making.

Comment: Could you make this an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) as there are some ambiguous classes there (what to import for Sprite, for example).

Comment: Ok, hope this is SSCCE now ;)
I found out that if i draw the tiles shifted tilewidth/2 to the left it works perfectly, but id still like to find out where my error was in the calculation, as this is just a workarround not a fix for the equation ;)

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Ryu Kajiya: SSCCE made it really easy to answer, in a way not possible without it.

Comment: Now only part i still dont like about this code are the boundaries while dragging. Left and right border are fine but top and bottom sort of fit for this tilesize, will be odd for another tilesize tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it for you.  Firstly I did a bit of algebra (hopefully explained by the inline comments) to simplify the calculation of which tile is hit.  The next bit you did somewhat realise; there's issues casting.  You need to convert *everything* to a double before you use it.  If you do `int/int` then you already made a cast and lost precision.

The trick to making it hit the right tile is 1) casting early and 2) the `+/- 0.5` which is used to force the return `int` cast to go one way or the other.  To elaborate, `(int)6.9 == 6`.

Here's the working answer:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (!Dragging) {
            /*
            // copy of the tile location assignment code as a reminder
            dx = x * GrassTile.getWidth() / 2
                    - y * GrassTile.getWidth() / 2;
            dy = x * GrassTile.getHeight() / 2
                    + y * GrassTile.getHeight() / 2;
            dx -= ViewLocation.x;
            dy -= ViewLocation.y;
            */
            int pickX = e.getX() + ViewLocation.x;
            int pickY = e.getY() + ViewLocation.y;
            int tileW = GrassTile.getWidth();
            int tileH = GrassTile.getHeight();
            /*
            // assignment code refactored
            x - y = 2 * pickX / tileW;
            x + y = 2 * pickY / tileH;

            // x+y= refactored to y=
            y = (2*pickY / tileH) - x;
            // substitute into x-y + refactor
            2x = (2 * pickX / tileW) + (2 * pickY / tileH);

            // x+y= refactored to x=
            x = (2*pickY / tileH) - y;
            // substitute x-y + refactor
            -2y = (2 * pickX / tileW) - (2 * pickY / tileH);
            2y = (2 * pickY / tileH) - (2 * pickX / tileW);
            */
            int hitx = (int)(((double)pickX / (double)tileW) + ((double)pickY / (double)tileH) - 0.5);
            int hity = (int)(((double)pickY / (double)tileH) - ((double)pickX / (double)tileW) + 0.5);
            Selected.setLocation(hitx, hity);
            repaint();
            //System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm that way. But why not use Math.Floor() and Math.Ceil() instead of those +-0,5 ?

Comment: Either way works.  A while ago I was using the casting for efficiency, but you are right.  Math.Floor() and Math.Ceil() are clearer approaches and you use use that.

Comment: "If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double."—[JLS §5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6.2)

Comment: @trashgod: true but I like to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

[`Polygon`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) implements the `Shape` interface, so one of the several `contain()` variations may simplify your calculation. The `createTransformedShape()` method of [`AffineTransform`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html) may also be helpful, as suggested in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/point-in-polygon).

Comment: I only used polygons to simplify the example code. I actualy use images as tiles so transforming their shape is not neccesary, because they are allready isometric. If i would wrap a polygon arround every tile i would have to create one arround every tile. I like to keep things simple and memory efficient so i discarded that solution early on. Also would also have to either shift the coordinates of all the poligons arround on dragging or have an equation to calculate the view coordnates to map coordinates wich brings me back to my current problem.

Comment: Using the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) would mitigate the overhead considerably and still simplify the geometry. `createTransformedShape()` would only be required to translate, not rotate or shear.

Comment: Well this would be a good way if i would use that for a real game or something like that, but in this case its just a graphical representation of table data, so i wanted to keep things as simple as possible. It would still need a working equation for the picking too.
But thanks for the suggestion, would probably be usefull in another of my projects.